# Convert number to string in n1ql query output from Couchbase DB

Tags: couchbase, tostring, data-conversion, sql++

I need the below value as a string in N1QL query output from Couchbase DB.

Current -

```
"cas": 1499937943452123136
```

Expected -

```
"cas": "1499937943452123136"
```

Cbq Query:

```
select meta().cas from sampledb where type = "PROD" and Id = 
"PROD_101"
```

Request your help.

Answer (score 4):

Use the to_string function.

```
select to_string(meta().cas) from sampledb where type = "PROD" and Id = "PROD_101"
```

What version of Couchbase are you using ?

Comment: Hi @kbinstance, The result is a string now, but it has rounded off the last 2 digits. Output is "cas": "1499937943452123100". But I need the value as **"cas": "1499937943452123136"**.

Comment: When TO_STRING argument exceed certain values and assigned to float it losses a precision. This is fixed in feature release.

Comment: @Emraan : As vsr said, this is a known issue and has been fixed in the upcoming release for 5.0 beta.

Answer (score 1):

To convert String to Number use **to_string()** method like given below example

[image]

If you want to convert string to number use **TONUMBER()** method like given below example

**Query:**

```
select sum(TONUMBER(installmentPremium)) TotalInstallmentPremium  from data
where installmentPremium > "10" and type_="ProductComponentOption" limit 100;
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "TotalInstallmentPremium": 15757.470000000001
  }
]
```